# Non-isomorphic labeled forests

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Prove that the number of non-isomorphic labeled forests on the vertex set [n] is at least p(n) (the number of partitions of the integer n).

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott How do I begin to show that it is at least p(n) if there is no closed formula for p(n)? Intuitively, i believe the statement but I do not know how to begin this proof.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Just show how to construct a unique labelled forest on $[n]$ from each partition of $n$; you can do it in such a way that each tree is a chain, for instance.

For example, from the partition $7=3+2+1+1$ I might construct the following labelled forest:

```
                     1---2---3   4---5   6   7
```